# How can i invoke lambda function correctly?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create my first Lambda function on AWS.
I'm following a YouTube tutorial and I wrote the following code in order to get some Users from the DynamoDB online service.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
aws.config.update({
region : "eu-west-3"
})

const dynamodb = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
const dynamoUsersTable = "Users"
const usersPath = "/users" 

exports.handler  = async (event) => {
console.log('Request event : ', event);
let response;

switch (true) {
    case event.httpMethod === 'GET' && event.path === usersPath:
        response = await getAllUsers();
        break;

    default:
        break;
} 
// UPDATED ANSWER - ADDED RETURN RESPONSE LIGNE ! -> New error : Missing Authentication Token
  return response;
}

const buildResponse = (statusCode, body) => {
return {
    statusCode : statusCode,
    headers : {
        "content-type" : "application/json"
    },
    body : JSON.stringify(body)
}
}

const scanDynamoRecords = async (scanParams, itemArray ) => {
try {
  const dynamoData = await dynamodb.scan(scanParams).promise();
  itemArray = itemArray.concat(dynamoData.Items);
  if (dynamoData.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    scanParams.ExclusiveStartkey = dynamoData.LastEvaluatedKey;
    return await scanDynamoRecords(scanParams, itemArray);
  }
  return itemArray;
} catch(error) {
  console.error('Do your custom error handling here. I am just gonna log it: ', error);
}
}
const getAllUsers = async () => {
const params = {
  TableName: dynamoUsersTable
}
const allUsers = await scanDynamoRecords(params, []);
const body = {
  users: allUsers
}
return buildResponse(200, body);
}
```

But apparently, I get Internal Server Error when I make my GET Request on Postman :

[image]

PS: The function has DynamoDBFullAccess Policy and CloudWatch Policy, and I can't find the error message log on cloud watch.

---

UPDATE: The error was that I had a missing "return" statement after the switch, however and after the fix, "Missing Authentication Token" message is returned as a response from a GET request on Postman. I'm suspecting that IAM has a say in this since I'm using multiple AWS services.

Comment: *"i can't find error message log on cloud watch."* - why? Do you see any logs? Put in a lot more debug logging statements.

Comment: Your code does not have an error handler, which means when the code breaks - there's it simply kills the lambda function without any further ado. Could you try wrapping your code in a try..catch?

Comment: where is your access keys for the sdk?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra OP has mentioned in their question he's using an IAM role with a couple of IAM policies that grant the required permissions to the Lambda function

Comment: The problem mentioned in the code above has been solved, i had a missing "return response" after the switch. However second answer seems more reasonable since i had another error message that says : "Missing Authentication Token".

Comment: I voted to close this. On SO you get to ask one question per post. Once you got the answer to your first question you should have posted a 2nd question concerning the token issue. Because of your edits, the question is now a mess and the answers no longer make sense and this needed to be closed so as not to confuse future readers. I'm taking the time to write this comment to explain this because it's not a bad question as such and wouldn't want you to not ask questions again in the future.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Thank you very much sir for your effort to make this forum reliable and I'm glad I had the chance to get to know more about good practices while demanding consultation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an Lambda function, you define an IAM role that is used to run the Lambda function. If your Lambda function is going to invoke other AWS Services, then you need to create an IAM role that has permissions to invoke those given services. If you do not correctly setup the IAM role permissions, then your Lambda function is not successful.

See this AWS tutorial. Although it is implemented in Java, it covers important information such as setting up an IAM role to invoke AWS services from the Lambda function, and so on.

[Creating scheduled events to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events)

Comment: You're right sir, I did specify an IAM Role when I created the Lambda function, and that role has a AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess, CloudWatchLogsFullAccess and AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole policies. On the other hand, the code is deployed withing Lambda service and API Gateway service. I don't understand where the unauthorized invocation happen exactly, and is there any kind of access configuration should be made for Lambda or API Gateway ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the `response` variable in your `handler` method.

Comment: That's true sir, however another message has been sent as response, which is authentication token is missing, how can i fix that, does it have something to do with IAM Roles ? Thank you very much.